# Knockoutjs binding to Property vs Property()

Tags: knockout.js

I can write a knockoutjs data binding expression in two different ways:

```
1. <div data-bind="text: FirstName"></div>
2. <div data-bind="text: FistName()"></div>
```

Note the two parens after FirstName in the second example. They both seem to work. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference.

They will only work *both* if `FirstName` is a `ko.observable`. If it is a plain value, only the first variant will work.

An observable does not hold its value directly. It is a function that *provides access* to the value. Therefore it must be *called* to get the value (i.e., strictly correct is `text: FistName()`).

But knockout is helpful and anticipates that. Therefore it will call the observable for you if you did not do it yourself.

Responsible for this is the helper function `ko.utils.unwrapObservable()`, which takes a parameter, determines whether it is an observable or a plain value and returns its value in both cases.

Knockout uses this function on every binding you define, so it does not matter if you call the observable yourself (`text: FistName()`) or let knockout do it behind the scenes (`text: FirstName`).

---

**Quirk:**

Knockout parses the binding expression `<binding>: <expr>` and determines whether `<expr>` is a simple identifier or something more complex.

Whenever `<expr>` is a simple identifier—like `FirstName`—knockout will apply `unwrapObservable()` automatically, because the situation is unambiguous.

But whenever `<expr>` is more complex—like `'Dear ' + FirstName`—knockout constructs a custom function from the expression. Now things become ambiguous and you are required to call the observable yourself, like this: `'Dear ' + FirstName()`.

Compare: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/cU4qw/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to read the following article:
[[10 Things to Know About KnockoutJS]](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html)

Quote from the article:

> Most bindings will call `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` on the value passed
>   to it, which will safely return the value for both observables and
>   non-observables. However, in a binding if you use an observable in an
>   expression, then you need to reference it as a function. Likewise, in
>   code you typically need to reference your observables as functions,
>   unless you actually want to pass the observable itself (not the
>   value).

```
<div data-bind="visible: someFlag">...</div>
<div data-bind="visible: !someFlag()">...</div>
```