# Datetime showing up as GMT in view using knockout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I've got the following code being pulled from SQL Server with Linq:

```
UserList = (from u in userQuery
            select new UserViewModel
                       {
                            {...}
                            LastUpdate = u.LastUpdate,
                            {...}
                       }).AsQueryable();
```

I put in a breakpoint and see the correct datetime that's getting pulled down and it is in my local timezone.

This is sent up to the view via JSON:

```
        <tr>
            <td>Last Updated</td>
            <td>
                <div data-bind="text: SelectedUser().LastUpdate" class="detailFields"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

But now the datetime is showing as "GMT" instead of my local time.

Where am I going wrong?

Updated code:

Installed moment.js, imported and changed the line to:

```
<div data-bind="text: moment(SelectedUser().LastUpdate()).format('LLL')" class="detailFields"></div>
```

NOTE the () after the LastUpdate variable name...

Comment: Do you have `moment.js` installed?

Comment: Is that a knockout JS? I just scanned my installed JS files for this project and it doesn't appear that it's there.

Comment: No, `moment.js` is a helper library to handle the date-time-of-javascript-hell... it' makes things easier. date-times can be hard, local time, GMT etc. Posting, displaying: they all seem to behave different. Take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148572/knockout-js-format-date-item

Comment: I'm using this:                     <div data-bind="text: moment(SelectedUser().LastUpdate).format('LL')" class="detailFields"></div> but it's coming up as "Invalid Date" but it's the same as the article you linked.  Can you see what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: `Invalid Date`; it indicates that LastUpdate might have an invalid value. Have you checked that?

Comment: I can remove the moment() from the datetime and it shows the datetime as GMT

Comment: I needed a () after the LastUpdate...  That fixed it! Thanks! did you want to make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invalid date of this line:

```
data-bind="text: moment(SelectedUser().LastUpdate).format('LLL')"
```

Is due to the fact that `knockout.js` want's it to be like:

```
data-bind="text: moment(SelectedUser().LastUpdate()).format('LLL')"
```

In general, when using and binding to knockout's observables, you need to put the `()` after them. More details on this subject can be found here: [Knockoutjs binding to Property vs Property()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948511/knockoutjs-binding-to-property-vs-property#11948715)